# How can I access iPhone's new 3D touch in Safari with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, 3dtouch

Apple has announced that with its new iPhone 6S and 6S+, [users can now use pressure to interact with their apps](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/3d-touch/). Is there a JavaScript API for web developers to take advantage of this new functionality on standard websites as well? If so, how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the W3C, [a new `force` property has been recently added to the spec of the `Touch` interface](https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#widl-Touch-force), which ranges from 0 (min force) to 1 (max force). This is already available for Safari on iOS9 (not sure if Chrome, or other browsers have implemented it yet).

**Quick answer:**

To access this property, simply invoke

```
touchForce = evt.originalEvent.touches[0].force;
```

within a `touchstart` or `touchmove` event listener.

**There are a few problems with this implementation:**

- On `touchstart`, the force will be very close to 0, as it's called as soon as the first sign of pressure is detected.
- The `touchstart` event won't fire again if pressure is increased or decreased.
- `touchmove` isn't reliable because you have to wait for position to change before the new `force` is read, which won't always be the case.

**Solution:**

To remedy this, you can set a timeout that evaluates this force every few milliseconds after `touchstart` and then clear the timeout on `touchend`.

```
var tO = 0;
$("#div1").on("touchstart", startTouch);
$("#div1").on("touchend", endTouch);

function startTouch(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    touchForce = evt.originalEvent.touches[0].force;
    tO = window.setTimeout(function(){startTouch(evt)}, 100);
    // Do something with touchForce
}

function endTouch(){
    touchForce = 0;
    window.clearTimeout(tO);
    // Do something else
}
```

[Try it out in this CodePen I created](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZYZxm)

It's a bit hacky, but it works. Maybe in the future they'll create a new `forcechange` event, but this is all we have for now.

Excuse the JQuery, I used it to illustrate the point more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the JS library [Pressure.js](https://pressurejs.com). It makes it really easy to get Force and 3D Touch values on iOS and OSX if you have an iPhone 6s or new Macbook with the new Force Touch trackpads.

The syntax is really simple too, here is an example:

```
Pressure.set('#element', {
  start: function(){
    // this is called on force start
  },
  end: function(){
    // this is called on force end
  },
  startDeepPress: function(){
    // this is called on "force click" / "deep press", aka once the force is greater than 0.5
  },
  endDeepPress: function(){
    // this is called when the "force click" / "deep press" end
  },
  change: function(force, event){
    // this is called every time there is a change in pressure
    // here the 'force' variable passed in container the current pressure force
  },
  unsupported: function(){
    // this is called once there is a touch on the element and the device or browser does not support Force or 3D touch
  }
});
```